# Combo Box OwnerDrawFixed - Scrolling very fast

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written the following code to increase the height of the item. Once this is done, while scrolling the combo, it is moving at a very high speed compared to the normal combo box. How can I fix this issue?

I have set the Draw Mode as DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

```
 private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {           
        e.DrawBackground();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.State);
        if (e.Index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }       
        SizeF stringMeasure = e.Graphics.MeasureString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + ((e.Bounds.Height - ItemHeight)/2 ), e.Bounds.Width, ItemHeight);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), rec);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void comboBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ItemHeight = this.ItemHeight * 2; ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MeasureItem event only gets called when the DrawMode is set for OwnerDrawVariable.

So you need to either change the DrawMode to OwnerDrawVariable, or set the ComboBox's ItemHeight property to the value of `this.ItemHeight * 2`

Not sure about the scrolling speed, that could just be your operating system.  I didn't notice much of a difference — you aren't using your `stringMeasure` variable so you can comment that out.

Comment: It looks like the problem appears only in my machine.